# How to replacing bundle identifier generated by Xcode, How to test iPad app to mac catalyst on another mac, How to make live

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, ipad, mac-catalyst

I successfully build, run and convert iPad app to mac catalyst.

I have problems in below questions to make live, testing mac catalyst app(iPad to mac catalyst app). does anyone have idea? please let me know if miss something.

(1) How to replacing bundle identifier generated by Xcode for iPad app to mac catalyst
I prefer below Apple developer account [Apple developer docs's link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/mac_catalyst/replacing_the_mac_bundle_id_provided_by_xcode?language=objc) but not getting success.

(2) is it necessary to make Mac Distribution profile with mac distribution certificate or all in one iOS Distribution certificate (Support Xcode 11.0 Later)

(3) How to test iPad Mac catalyst app to other mac book.

(4) is it necessary to make separate build for mac catalyst to live (iPad app to) mac catalyst app.

Answer (score 0):

1. I could not change the identifier
2. In my case, the xcode did everything myself
3. [Use this and save .app file. After that you can shared it to others macbooks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ly0r8.png)
4. As you prefer, but if you plan to make a lot of changes, then yes